# Emacs package install script in init file

Tags: emacs

I restructured my Emacs init files to put them under version control. The file system layout looks like that:

```
/home/axel/.user_config/emacs
├── development.el
├── general.el
├── init.el
├── packages.el
└── writing.el
```

`packages.el` contains a list of packages Emacs should install on startup if they are not already installed. This works without problems after I do a `rm -rf ~/.emacs.d/*`. When I start Emacs afterwards, all the packages listed in `packages.el` are installed. However, when I manually add a package to (e.g. `markdown-mode+`) to the list `pfl-packages` in `packages.el` the new package is not installed when I restart Emacs. Deleting the contents of `~/.emacs.d/` again solves that problem, but I would like to be able to add package names to the list, which Emacs then automatically installs on startup. Am I missing something crucial about the Emacs initialization process?

Please see the content of the relevant files below.

The file `~/.emacs`contains the following:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.user_config/emacs/")
(load-library "init")
```

The file `~/.user_config/emacs/init.el` contains:

```
;;;; loads the different libraries to set up Emacs accordingly

;; load the library that sets up package repositories and syncing
(load-library "packages")

;; load the library that sets up the general behavior of Emacs
(load-library "general")
(load-library "writing")
(load-library "development")
```

The file `packages.el` contains the following:

```
;;;; this library sets up package repositories and allows for syncing    packages
;;;; between different machines
;;;; to add packages to the syncing, add their repository names to the   list `pfl-packages'

;;; set up package repositories from which additional packages can be installed

;; set up ELPA and MELPA repositories
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
                     '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives
                     '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/"))


;;; set up package syncing to allow for syncing between different machines

;; list of packages to sync
(setq pfl-packages
        '(
            color-theme-sanityinc-solarized
            company
            company-auctex
            company-c-headers
            company-irony
            company-quickhelp
            elpy
            ess
            flycheck-irony
            irony
            magit
            markdown-mode
            markdown-mode+
            rainbow-delimiters
            smart-tabs-mode
            yasnippet
            ))

;; refresh package list if it is not already available
(when (not package-archive-contents) (package-refresh-contents))

;; install packages from the list that are not yet installed
(dolist (pkg pfl-packages)
    (when (and (not (package-installed-p pkg)) (assoc pkg package-archive-contents))
        (package-install pkg)))
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In my `~/.emacs.d` directory, I have in my `init.el` the following:

```
(load "~/.emacs.d/init-packages")
```

In `init-packages.el` I have done exactly what you want to do: upon startup, emacs checks whether every package listed is already installed, and, if not, it is installed. When you want a new package installed, you just add it to the list.

It's worth noting that `package-initialize` has to be called after adding the relevant package archives, so that they can actually be fetched and then installed.

Below is the contents of `init-packages.el`:

```
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("elpy" . "http://jorgenschaefer.github.io/packages/"))

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "http://melpa-stable.milkbox.net/packages/") t)

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/")


; list the packages you want
(setq package-list
    '(python-environment deferred epc 
        flycheck ctable jedi concurrent company cyberpunk-theme elpy 
        yasnippet pyvenv highlight-indentation find-file-in-project 
        sql-indent sql exec-path-from-shell iedit
        auto-complete popup let-alist magit git-rebase-mode 
        git-commit-mode minimap popup))


; activate all the packages
(package-initialize)

; fetch the list of packages available 
(unless package-archive-contents
  (package-refresh-contents))

; install the missing packages
(dolist (package package-list)
  (unless (package-installed-p package)
    (package-install package)))
```

Hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I compared my setup to yours and it seems that the problem in my setup was the order of `(package-initialize)` and `(add-to-list ...)`. Putting `(package-initialize)` after `(add-to-list ...)` solved the problem.

Perhaps you can edit your reply a bit to make it more clear for other readers?

Comment: No problem, glad it was of help. Just made an edit there.

Comment: I've tried this and this is not working for me on a fresh install since package list is not yet loaded from the repos and Emacs fails to install packages. I had to add a `(unless package-archive-contents (package-refresh-contents))` to the script.

Comment: How do you make packages "available" for `(package-install)` to work? `(package-install)` reports package is not available before I list all packages manually with `M-x list-packages`.